# How solve conversion thing in python that int() can't convert '\x002\x002\x001\x000\x00' into integer?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, int, type-conversion

I have some weird problem with python `int` function.
I read some file with numeric values and convert these to integers.
When I do this locally it's goes fine, but when I upload it to Google App Engine the conversion fails with error: 
`invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`

I tried to print the value it's trying to convert and it is 2210.

Then I tried to output whole splitted line from file and got this:
`['\x00B\x00a\x00u\x00w\x00e\x00n\x00s\x00', '\x002\x002\x001\x000\x00', '\x005\x004\x003\x001\x00', '\x005\x003\x007\x002\x00', '\x005\x002\x006\x005\x00', '\x005\x006\x001\x008\x00', '\x005\x003\x002\x008\x00\r\x00']`

I use that code to convert: `int(splitted_line[j])`

And I am very new to python. Could someone say what I need to do?

Comment: Looks like some form of unicode so possibly try `int(splitted_line[j].decode("utf-8"))` or `int(splitted_line[j].decode("utf-16"))`

Comment: @KeefBaker - I tried both, but no changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an encoding issue, but a quick workaround would be to remove '\x00' from each string before converting it. So try `int(splitted_line[j].replace('\x00',''))`

Comment: That bypassed the exception, but led into another problem that I can't currently debug. I hope for some another solution.

Comment: I'd suggest that you go one step back and check the encoding of the file. How do you read it currently? If `with open()` doesn't work then you can try to `import codecs` and open your file specifying the encoding.

Comment: That's the file that user uploads to web page. Then I do this: `file_data = uploaded_file.file.read()` It doesn't requires to be opened. Now I think that I getting file byte content instead of strings.